# How to make bulk update with join on Sequelize (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 models (parent-child): items and cart_items defined with Sequelize.
Relations:

```
db.items.hasMany(db.cart_items, { foreignKey: 'itemId' });
db.cart_items.belongsTo(db.items, { foreignKey: 'itemId' });
```

items have price fiels, cart_items have itemPrice field which i need to update with item.price field.

I need to make **bulk** update of child model with data from parent model. Is it possible with Sequelize?
Something like this:

```
db.cart_items.update(
        // values
        { itemPrice: db.items.price }, // Related parent item model = 0
        // options
        { where: this.getCartItemsQueryObj(userId) } // This is ok
      );
```

I can do it with raw mysql query:

```
return db.sequelize.query(`
        UPDATE cart_items ci
        JOIN items i
          ON ci.itemId = i.id
        SET ci.itemPrice = i.price
        WHERE ci.userId=:userId AND ci.orderId IS NULL`,
        { replacements: { userId: userId }, type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE }
      );
```

Comment: I can't say for sure but I don't think this is possible. You might need to execute the SQL directly for this kind of update.